# Wait for MouseListener in method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a static method in which I add a `MouseListener` to an existing `JPanel` (with an existing mouse listener) and want to stop the method until the mouse listener gives a signal.

Tried:

```
public Object sync;
public static void main(){
    //do someThing
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mE) {
                                 synchronized(Main.sync) {
                                       sync.notify();
                                 }
                                }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mE) {
                                }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mE) {
                                }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mE) {
                                }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mE) {
                                }

                            });
   synchronized(Main.sync) {                 
    try{
         Main.sync.wait();
    }catch(exeption e){
         //do nothing
    }
}
    //continue
}
```

But the application just stop responding when it reaches the wait statement; I'm completely new to thread management so would be grateful for explanations.

Tried:

```
 public Object sync;
 public static void main(){
    //do someThing
    SwingUtilitys.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mE) {
                      synchronized(Main.sync) {
                           sync.notify();
                      }
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mE) {
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mE) {
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mE) {
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mE) {
                }

             });
        });
   synchronized(Main.sync) {                 
    try{
         Main.sync.wait();
    }catch(exeption e){
         //do nothing
    }
}
}
```

and it worked fine. thanks to ContAltDEl.

Comment: The problem is likely to be that you are calling wait on the UIDispatchThread. If that's the case, no other events can be dispatched while the thread is waiting and thus you are in deadlock. You can't wait and notify on the same thread

Comment: It appears to be in main method, but there is no String[] parameter. Where is it called from?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)